# How to prove "the position of any subset range of an ordered set, after random permutation, cannot be determined if the permutation unknown"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

To clarify the problem, for example, the subset (consecutive) range $S=\{2, 3, 4\}$ of the set $U=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$. Given $U$ is ordered, the position of $S$ corresponding to $U$ can be determined, i.e., the starting position is $2$. Consider that $S$ is obfuscated by some random permutation, say $\delta(S)$. If the permutation $\delta$ is unknown to a distinguisher $P$, only given $U$ and $\delta(S)$, $P$ will not be able to infer the position of $S$ corresponding to $U$.

The conclusion seems straightforward, but I would like a rigorous mathematical proof. Intuitively, the mathematical induction can be used. I have a rough idea like, assume $|U|=m$, for any $|\delta(S)|=1$, the position of $\delta(S)$ corresponding to $U$ cannot be determined. Then suppose it holds for $|\delta(S)|=m-2$. Then when $|\delta(S)|=m-1$, it is still valid. Anyone can help me with it? Better provide a complete proof or at least some rough ideas.

Comment: What is exactly a position? Do you mean minimal element? Also, what does "given $\delta(S)$" mean? Note that speaking about sets and permutations seem problematic, since the order in a set does not matter.

Comment: maybe "set" is not a good term here. What I am trying to say is an ordered sequence U. $\delta(S)$ means applying the permutation to S.  The position of S according to U can be referred to as which part of U, S belongs to. Or can use the starting element of S to indicate the position as  shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase your problem: you consider a finite sequence $U=(u_1,\dots,u_N)$ and a subsequence $S=(u_p,u_{p+1},\dots,u_{p+l})$ of *consecutive* (*) terms of $U$ is extracted from $U$, without your knowledge. The only thing you know is a permutation $S_\sigma=(u_{\sigma(p)},\dots,u_{\sigma(p+l)})$ of $S$ by a permutation $\sigma$.

Your question is: can I recover $S$ knowing $U$? How to prove that I cannot recover $S$?

The thing is: **in general**, you cannot recover $U$. To justify it, a counter-example is enough: imagine that $U=(1,2,3,2,1,3,2,3,1,2)$ and $S_\sigma=(1,2,3)$. Since $U$ contains all possible permutations of $(1,2,3)$, then you cannot know which one you started from.

Can you prove that you can **never** recover $S$? Nope, since if $U$ has some very precise structure, you may be able to do it. For example, if $U$ is ordered as the example above, $S$ is also ordered, so you can determine it by reordering $S_\sigma$.

(*): correct me if I am wrong on that point, but it doesn't really change the problem.

Comment: Thank you. I think it is still my fault that some additional conditions are missed in the original question. With your notations, the terms of the sequence $U$ increases monotonically without duplication, like integer sequence   $\{1,2,3,...,N\}$, so the subsequence  $S$ is also monotonically increasing. Apart from applying a random permutation \sigma to S, a masking one-way function $f$ is also used to hide the original term u_i in U and you cannot find u_i given f(u_i). For example, U={1,2,3,4,5,6} and S={2,3,4}. After applying f and \sigma, maybe S_{sigma&f}={f(3),f(2),f(4)}.

Comment: Given only U and without the knowledge of f and \sigma, you cannot recover S